# Is there a way to make an automatic redistribution smart contract?

Tags: ether, smart-contract-wallets

I would like to make a smart contract, which will automaticaly redistribute the tokens sent to it to other addresses, is that possible ?

Example : I send 1 token X to the contract, when the contract receives it, 0.1 token X are sent to 10 different addresses automaticaly

Ty for you help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this natively (for utility tokens such as ETH) with the fallback function `receive` - see [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html?highlight=receive#receive-ether-function) here, although you may encounter issues due to the default gas limit for transfers.

For ERC20 tokens there's no auto-callback so instead of normal transfers, users will have to call a special function you implement in that distribution contract.

The other way to do it is waiting for tokens to accrue there and calling (as owner) a distribution task from time to time (either yourself or through a keeper/gelato bot).

Comment: Thanks ! I have managed to create a simple contract who sends back ETH, but now I would like to make the same contract for an ERC20 token, could you tell me what the function to do it might look like pls ? Ty again

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with something like [Gelato Ops](https://app.gelato.network/#/).

[image: Gelato Ops]

Answer (score 0):

For your ERC20, you can make use of the IERC20 interface.

Import the IERC20 interface if you have the file. You can check openzepellin's library for the file.

Enclose your erc20 contract address in your IERC20 and use the transfer function to redistribute it: `IERC20(erc20ContractAddress).transfer(recipient, amount)`